# How can I ensure that a specific child element is always displayed in a parent, even when the content is too large to fit all of the children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent element with `display: flex` that contains a bunch of children. 
The problem is, that sometimes there are too many children to properly fit inside the parent.

However, I would like that, no matter what, if there are too many children, the last element visible in the parent should always be the element with the class `always-show`.

In other words, if I have a parent that can support 3 children but there are in fact more than three, I want it to look like this:

[image: css-flex-last-item]

Is there any way I can force the last element (the `More...`) to stay stuck to the right and not get pushed out of the `div`? As you can see in my snippet, the yellow box is getting displayed and the `More...` isn't. I would like the yellow box to get hidden and the `More...` to show

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 365px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ababab;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}
.pink{
  background-color: pink;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child brown"></div>
  <div class="child pink"></div>
  <div class="child green"></div>
  <div class="child yellow"></div>
  <div class="always-show"><a>More...</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't understood but as I see you want to link to show more and less , for this you can use jQuery ref. https://codepen.io/stanyy/pen/QevYVO

Comment: I would prefer not having to use Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:sticky`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 365px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ababab;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}

.pink{
  background-color: pink;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.always-show {
  position:sticky;
  right:0;
  background-color: #ababab;
  height: 102px;
  line-height:102px;
}

.parent :nth-last-child(2) {
  position:relative;
}
.parent :nth-last-child(2):after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  left:100%;
  margin-left:2px;
  width:100px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:#ababab
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child brown"></div>
  <div class="child pink"></div>
  <div class="child green"></div>
  <div class="child yellow"></div>
  <div class="always-show"><a>More...</a></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child brown"></div>
  <div class="child pink"></div>
  <div class="always-show"><a>More...</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to NOT show `More...` in the second example? Since there are only two elements, I don't want it to say `More...`

Comment: nice stuff! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you want something like this?

```css
.p-parent{
  display:inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
  position:relative
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 365px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ababab;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}
.pink{
  background-color: pink;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.always-show{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  background:white;
  padding:.5rem
}
```

```html
<div class="p-parent">
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child brown"></div>
  <div class="child pink"></div>
  <div class="child green"></div>
  <div class="child yellow"></div>
  <div class="always-show"><a>More...</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For static no of child you can give order to yellow box as below

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 365px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ababab;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  order:5;
}
.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}
.pink{
  background-color: pink;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child brown"></div>
  <div class="child pink"></div>
  <div class="child green"></div>
  <div class="child yellow"></div>
  <div class="always-show"><a>More...</a></div>
</div>
```